# Azure: Programar tarea de reinicio de servidor desde el panel de azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Buenas día a todos,
necesito saber: Se puede programar una tarea para el reiniciar el servidor desde el portal de azure?

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos. 
Si puedes hacerlo desde el portal, pero tienes que crear un proceso de automatizacion.

Aqui un ejemplo:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2015/09/07/scheduling-start-and-stop-times-for-azure-vms/

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido!